# react native card view goes outside of screen width

Tags: react-native

When my card view has no width in css and my text is really big inside, the card extends past the width of the screen. When I have a fixed width on the card, the text inside of it goes outside the card. I am using react-native-cardview. Anyone have any solution to this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Shain. Consider [Taking a tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and also see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Whenever you ask a question try including your code snippet, along with what you tried, and what thought pattern do you use, and aks specific questions.

Comment: the solution is using Dimensions for responsive size, and try to make your own card view using View or Touchable instead